# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.

```
public Collection<AdDistribution> getAdDistribution(byte srch, byte cont) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {

    List<AdDistribution> mediums = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AdDistribution> adDistribution = new ArrayList<>();
            adDistribution.add(AdDistribution.SEARCH);
            adDistribution.add(AdDistribution.CONTENT);
            if (adDistribution.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
              }

    if (srch == 0 && cont == 0) {
        mediums = new ArrayList<>();
        mediums.set(0, adDistribution.get(0));
    }
    if (srch == 1 || cont == 1) {
        mediums = new ArrayList<>();
        if (srch == 1) {
            mediums.set(0, adDistribution.get(0));
        } else if (cont == 1) {
            mediums.set(0, adDistribution.get(1));
        }
    }
    if (srch == 1 && cont == 1) {
        mediums = new ArrayList<>();
        mediums.set(0, adDistribution.get(0));
        mediums.set(1, adDistribution.get(1));
    }
            return mediums;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that you are using set method to update element at index 0

> set(index,value) method needs an element to present at that index

but you haven't added any element at that position in medium arraylist before that .

So you need to first add an element at index 0 thereafter only you can update it with set method

Answer (score 7):

You need to use

```
mediums.add(adDistribution.get(0));
```

rather than `mediums.set(0, adDistribution.get(0));` etc.

[`ArrayList.set(int, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) requires there to be an element to replace:

> **Replaces** the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.
>
> Throws:
>   `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

In a new list, `size() == 0`, so `set(0, something)` fails.

Comment: Can u share the  modified code

Comment: In my answer: "You need to use [modified code] rather than [your code]". Sorry, that's all you're getting from me: you need to put in a bit of effort yourself.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I just removed the unnecessary if statements and simplified them to make your code more readable.
Then I have replaced the **set** functions with the **add** function, because the set only can set existing elements.

EDIT2: Based on Andy Turner's answer, I modified my code. Thank you for the suggestions!

After these modifications, the code should look like this (add/remove/modify it for your needs):

```
public Collection<AdDistribution> getAdDistribution(byte srch, byte cont) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {

    List<AdDistribution> mediums = new ArrayList<>();

    if( ( srch == 0 && cont == 0 ) || srch == 1 ) {
        mediums.add(AdDistribution.SEARCH);
    }

    if( cont == 1 ) {
        mediums.add(AdDistribution.CONTENT);
    }

    return mediums;
}
```

Comment: "I just removed the unnecessary if statements" you could also remove `if (adDistribution.isEmpty()) {`, which is never false. `adDistribution` is also redundant: just add `AdDistribution.SEARCH` and `AdDistribution.CONTENT` directly to `mediums`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. At first I did not pay attention to those parts of code, I should have been more accurate about everything. I have edited my comment. Regards!