# Why am I getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error in this substring method?

Tags: java, android, substring

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

...

ABV = elem.select("td > span.muted").text();
Log.d("myLOG_ABV", ABV);
Log.d("myLOG_ABVlength", String.valueOf(ABV.length()));

/*String temp_ABV = ABV.substring(ABV.length()-6, ABV.length());*/

... }
```

Result

> D/myLOG_ABV: Russian River Brewing Company American Wild Ale | 7.50%
>   D/myLOG_ABVlength: 55

and then, I cancled the annotation code.

```
...

ABV = elem.select("td > span.muted").text();
Log.d("myLOG_ABV", ABV);
Log.d("myLOG_ABVlength", String.valueOf(ABV.length()));

***String temp_ABV = ABV.substring(ABV.length()-6, ABV.length());***

...
```

Result

> Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0;
>   index=-6

Why am I getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error in this substring method?

I got the result that 'ABVlength : 55' in my code with annotation.

But after cancellation of annotation, I got StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Seriously, I am fighting with this code for 7hours 30minutes.

Comment: Perhaps this code is executed multiple times, and in some of them `ABV` is empty.

Comment: The exception message says that you get it because the length of your string is 0. Why it’s 55 once and 0 another time — is impossible to tell from the code you have posted.

Comment: Closely related: [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077303/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-index-0-size-0-exception)

Comment: @Eran / Thanks Eran. It was perfectly right. This code is in the FOR sentence. I found that one of values is empty. So I got this error. Yesterday, I modified the code, and then I fixed it. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have:

```
***String temp_ABV = ABV.substring(ABV.length()-6, ABV.length());***

Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-6
```

How can you get an index of -6 in this situation? `ABV` must have zero length, i.e. `""`.

It may be the case that `ABV` should have at least six characters, but that indicates a bug elsewhere.

What to do?

First and foremost, validate your inputs.

Somewhere you would normally want something like:

```
if (abv.length() < 6) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
}
```

Next find where that value is coming from and fix the bug.

Looks like you're parsing some kind of external document. In this case you *may* want the handling to be more lenient:

```
int abvLen = abv.length();
int abvEndIndex = abvLen - 6;
if (abvEndIndex < 0) {
    log.error("ABV length less than 6", abv);
    abvEndIndex = 0;
}
String abvEnd = abv.substring(abvEndIndex, abvLen);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. My code was in the FOR sentence. I found that one of values is empty. So I got this error.
Yesterday, I modified the code. And then I fixed it. Thanks for sincere reply. :)